# Anamorphic Design Process

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, perspective

I'm hoping that designers that can lend their expertise on anamorphic designs. It is not a new concept but not a lot of info on how it can be done easily.

What are the steps involved to create anamorphic 3D pop-out effects?

Is there a software out there that simplifies the process or do I need to use Photoshop or Illustrator?

**I like to replicate the 3D floor graphics this company does below.**

http://www.shapeshiftermedia.com/gallery/floor-graphics/nicole-neubauer-kellerkind-3d-advertising-floor-train-station/

http://www.shapeshiftermedia.com/downloads/

Comment: Could you pick one or two of your favorites from that site and add them to your post using the built in image uploader?

Comment: There's a nice looking tool called BSAsidewalk3D that is available at http://bionware.com/3D.php that does this. There's a demo with limited functionality too. I'd quite like to figure out how it works out how much to distort a photo based on viewing height and distance.

Comment: I also noticed this duplicate question where the answer wasn't really answered (but there's some good reference material): http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28162/anamorphic-perspective-in-illustrator-or-photoshop

Comment: Finally... Though you can stretch and distort an image to get it to look like this, I suspect that a lot of the examples on that site are rendered (and projected onto a flat surface) in 3D rendering software.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is quite easy but requires some testing.

A) Take your original design, photo or whatever into Photoshop, and duplicate as a new layer.

B) Edit > Transform > Perspective. Add a perspective to counter the normal perspective. The amount of this depends on the angle and distance where you will be seeing the image.

C) Squeeze a bit your image. In my example is 66%.

[image]

D) You can take some scissors and cut your shape.

Depending on the quality of the image and how well it is lited this will blend better on the surroundings.

Comment: This is pretty simple and gets the job done. The amount the image needs to be perspective distorted (and stretched) will need to be varied depending on the angle it is to be viewed at. Perhaps there is a way to rule out experimentation using maths to figure out how much the image needs to be distorted.

Comment: One method could be proyecting a real scale image on a 3D model program (The contrary of what I just did) I did this images on blender. I could have done a grid and test it, but the girl is more interesting. :o)

Answer (score -3):

Yes, 3d anamorphic converted images are created by stretching an image 3 times length ways which dictates the viewing angle of an image similar to a trapezoid.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Can you expand your answer to explain a bit more about the process? If you want to know more about the site, please see [the help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!